# How to get saved query from view in bigquery

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery

Using the Python API, is there a way to retrieve the currently saved view query from Google Big Query?  I know I can get view metadata, but I need to be able to save off the actual query.  Thanks.

Comment: One way to get this is to find the `job` object that is associated with the creation of the view and grab its `query` attribute.

Comment: ok thanks.  what if I don't have that?  alot of the views are created by other people, and there's over 400 of them already.

Comment: I would recommend finding the specific job itself. `Client.list_jobs` will get you all the available jobs. Iterate through these jobs and find the job whose `destination` attribute produces a `TableReference` object that points to your `view`. That's honestly the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to get the details of the job that created the view. There's a much easier way. Simply get the `Table` object and examine its `view_query` property.

### Code

```
[..]
client = bigquery.Client('grey-sort-challenge')
dataset = client.dataset('apps_script_scheduler')
tables = list(client.list_dataset_tables(dataset))
for t in tables:
  table = client.get_table(t)
  print 'Table type: %s, SQL: %s' % (table.table_type, table.view_query)
[..]
```

### Output (for my dataset that contains 2 native tables and a view)

```
Table type: TABLE, SQL: None
Table type: TABLE, SQL: None
Table type: VIEW, SQL: SELECT
  SUM(views) AS total_views,
  title,
  LANGUAGE
FROM
  `bigquery-samples.wikipedia_benchmark.Wiki1M`
WHERE
  title LIKE '%Melbourne%'
GROUP BY
  title,
  LANGUAGE
ORDER BY
  total_views DESC;
```

Docs --> https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/reference.html#google.cloud.bigquery.table.Table.view_query

Comment: Thanks much!  this is awesome!

Comment: This answers my second question from [this issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/issues/4605). Thanks!